# QuickCheck 2 batch processing

Tags: haskell, batch-processing, quickcheck

The `Batch` module of QuickCheck was removed with [version 2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.1) ([1.2.0.1 still has it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-1.2.0.1)). Because of this, I'm always feeling like `mapM_`-ing multiple tests together is kind of hacky. Am I overlooking the successor feature in QuickCheck 2? Is there a canonical way of grouping independent tests together?

Comment: Look at [`test-framework`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework) and [`test-framework-quickcheck2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-quickcheck2).

Answer (score 10):

There's the 'go big or go home' option of grouping together all tests in the current module via `Test.QuickCheck.All`.  It requires Template Haskell, and all properties must begin with `prop_`.  Ex:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Test.QuickCheck.All

prop_one, prop_two :: a -> Bool
prop_one = const True
prop_two = const True

runTests :: IO Bool
runTests = $quickCheckAll

main :: IO ()
main = runTests >>= \passed -> if passed then putStrLn "All tests passed."
                                         else putStrLn "Some tests failed."
```

Comment: Two important notes: First, properties from imported modules don't seem to be included. Second, (and it looks very weird), in GHC 7.8 you need to insert `return []` before the line `runTests = $quickCheckAll`. See the [module haddock page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-All.html) for more information.

Comment: If you're testing through a cabal test-suite, this `main` would probably suit you better: `main = runTests >>= \passed -> if passed then exitSuccess else exitFailure`. And you'll also need to `import System.Exit(exitSuccess, exitFailure)`.